# MQ channel F5 reroute

Tags: ibm-mq, f5

I would like to know if it is possible to point a MQ Sender channel to a F5 Load balancer VIP address, rather than to a concrete MQ Server IP address and have the message delivered to one of two MQ servers in the F5 Cluster resources group. There are two MQ Servers in the F5 cluster.

What I'm trying to do, is determine if I could use this method in lieu of creating a MQ Cluster Gateway Queue manager, on yet more hardware and use the F5 LB feature to deliver the message to a cluster queue.

If I could capitalize on the F5 Load balancing, I'm thinking it would simulate a MQ Cluster Gateway Queue manager.

Would it work? Pitfalls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at a couple of issues with this configuration:

1. With persistent messages the Sender and the corresponding Receiver channels increment a sequence number with each persistent message sent across the channel.  If this sequence number does not match then the channel will not start unless it is reset to match on one end or the other (usually the Sender).  This means that if the sender channel connects to QMGR1 behind the F5, the Receiver on QMGR1 will increment the sequence number, if the next time the sender channel connects it is routed to QMGR2, the sequence number of the Receiver will be lower than it is on the sender and it will not start.
2. Even if you were only sending non-persistent messages which do not increment the sequence number, you would still not achieve the same results as you would with having a cluster gateway in front of the two queue managers.  Typically with a cluster configuration you would get a round robin of the messages between the two clustered queue managers.  With a sender channel it is normally configured to start when a message is put to the associated transmission queue (`TRIGGER`) and to keep running until messages have not been sent for the length of time specified on the disconnect interval (`DISCINT`).  Because of this you would not see workload balancing of messages between the two queue managers behind the F5.  Depending on how you have the F5 configured and how long the disconnect interval is set to you would see a group of messages to go one queue manager and then a group of messages go to the other queue manager.  The number of messages in each group would depend on the traffic pattern compared to the sender channel settings.

Note that even if the Sender channel is configured to connect only to one of the two clustered queue managers, if you set the cluster workload use queue (`CLWLUSEQ`) to the value of `ANY` for the clustered queue, you can have messages still round robin between the two instances of the queue.  This would require that you have the remote queue (`QREMOTE`) on the Sender channel queue manager specify a Remote Queue Manager Alias (`RQMA`) as the remote queue manager name (`RQMNAME`) value.  The RQMA would then allow the messages to resolve to any instance of the clustered queue including the local instance. Examples of objects are below for the Sender queue manager (`SQMGR`) and Receiver (first clustered) queue manager (`CQMGR1`) and the second clustered queue manager (`CQMGR2`):

**SQMGR:**

```
DEFINE QREMOTE(TO.CQLOCAL) RNAME(CQLOCAL) RQMNAME(CLUSTER.RQMA) XMITQ(CQMGR1)
DEFINE QLOCAL(CQMGR1) USAGE(XMITQ) INITQ(SYSTEM.CHANNEL.INITQ) TRIGDATA(SQMGR.CQMGR1) TRIGGER .....
DEFINE CHL(SQMGR.CQMGR1) CHLTYPE(SDR) XMITQ(CQMGR1) CONNAME(10.20.30.40) .....
```

**CQMGR1:**

```
DEFINE CHL(SQMGR.CQMGR1) CHLTYPE(RCVR) MCAUSER('notmqm') .....
DEFINE QREMOTE(CLUSTER.RQMA) RNAME('') RQMNAME('') XMITQ('')
DEFINE QLOCAL(CQLOCAL) CLUSTER('YOURCLUSTER') CLWLUSEQ(ANY)
```

**CQMGR2:**

```
DEFINE QLOCAL(CQLOCAL) CLUSTER('YOURCLUSTER') CLWLUSEQ(ANY)
```